# wxPython: text alignment does not work

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

For some reasons the wx.ALIGN_* does not align anything on Ubuntu, while it works on Mac OS X:

```
self.static_text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'hello, world', pos=(0,0), 
                                 size=(300,30), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
```

Any idea, what could it be?

**Update:** This was tried with wxPython 2.8.12.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2. wxPython 2.8.11.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.

**Update 2:** Does not work either on Debian 6.0.3 with wxPython 2.8.12.1

**Update 3:** All of the above was tested with Python 2.6

Comment: Someone encounters similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627730/why-is-my-text-not-aligning-properly-in-wxpython  Maybe you can write a bug report to the team of wxPython

Comment: Un Ubuntu this doesn't work. It is a bug that doesnt shows in windows at least in the last versions. In Ubuntu, you can get the text aligned by using a vertical box sizer using wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL and wx.ALIGN_RIGHT to add your StaticText. For a more general answer [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627730/why-is-my-text-not-aligning-properly-in-wxpython)

Answer (score 0):

I have test this code snippet in Win 7 environment, one error is surfaced about the argument usage: *SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg*

```
self.static_text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'hello, world', pos=(0,0), size=(300,30), style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
```

Cause you have used two keyword args ("pos" and "size") in front of wx.ALIGN_CENTER, which is non-keyword arg. I guess that change wx.ALIGN_CENTER into style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER may solve your problem ?

Comment: thanks for noting! however in my original code I didn't have that mistake, and the thing was not working.

Comment: http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian shows that latest supported release is Ubuntu 11.4 natty. I guess that you built your binary package from source code. Maybe the problem that you encountered is under resolving. This page also mentions that Debian 6.0 is well built with Python 2.6. (Maybe you can add the version of Python that you have tested)