# why is my text not aligning properly in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, alignment, wxwidgets

I'm using wxPython to build a GUI and I'm trying to align some text but it's not working at all.
I'm trying align three different static text items in three places (right aligned, center aligned, and left aligned) in three seperate panels. The result that I'm getting though is that all three static text controls are aligned in the top left corners of their respective panels.
[image: text not aligned]

This is code I have:

```
    self.lastText=wx.StaticText(self.textDisplayPanel1, label=self.lastWords, style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    self.currentText=wx.StaticText(self.textDisplayPanel2, label=self.currentWords, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
    self.nextText=wx.StaticText(self.textDisplayPanel3, label=self.nextWords, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
```

Any ideas on how I fix this?

Thank you!

**I'm running mac OSX 10.7.2 with Python 2.7.1 and wxPython 2.8.12.1**

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587060/wxpython-text-alignment-does-not-work/8612146#8612146

Comment: Maybe you can add information about your testing environment (OS, Python version, wxPython version).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:** Although everything commented below works on windows, the first option would not work on, for example, Ubuntu due to maybe a bug. A previous post given in the comments indicate that the same problem is found in OSX.
In any case, the second option using vertical sizers works both in Ubuntu and windows so you could try it on OSX.

---

Your text has the instruction to align in the way you want with `wx.ALIGN...` and, in fact, it is aligned. However the size of the StaticText is not that of the panel but just the size of the text. Having restricted its position to its own size, you can not see the diference between the alignment modes.

You have two options to solve the problem:

**Option 1.** Expand the StaticText widget size and position your text on it

You could expand the size of your StaticText widget using its `size` parameter. This is a bad solution except for fixed size parents or frames you are not going to change size or reuse in other applications. If the size of the widget containing the text changes then the relative position of the text will be also modified because its size stays fixed. So it is always better to organize your widgets by means of sizers.

The proportion of the available space the widget occupies in the sizer slot is given by the second parameter in `sizer.Add()` (`0` is minimal size, `1` is full occupation):

```
sizer_2.Add(self.label_1, 0, 0, 0)
```

[image]

To see the text aligned in the panel as you want you have to tell the StaticText to expand to all the space available:

```
sizer_2.Add(self.label_1, 1, 0, 0)
```

[image]

Here you have the relevant code:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.label_1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel_1, -1, "label_1", style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        self.panel_2 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.label_2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel_2, -1, "label_2", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.panel_3 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.label_3 = wx.StaticText(self.panel_3, -1, "label_3")

        self.panel_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 255, 0))
        self.panel_2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 255, 255))
        self.panel_3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(219, 112, 147))

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        sizer_2.Add(self.label_1, 1, 0, 0)
        sizer_3.Add(self.label_2, 1, 0, 0)
        sizer_4.Add(self.label_3, 1, 0, 0)

        self.panel_1.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        self.panel_2.SetSizer(sizer_3)
        self.panel_3.SetSizer(sizer_4)

        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
```

[image]

Note the code is longer than needed in order to mimick your example with three panels. You obtain the same frame view using one only panel. In fact it could be simplified further not using panels and setting the StaticText directly on the sizer:

```
class MyFrame2(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "label_1", style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        self.label_2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "label_2", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.label_3 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "label_3")

        self.label_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(127, 255, 0))
        self.label_2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 255, 255))
        self.label_3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(219, 112, 147))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.label_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.label_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.label_3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
```

**Option 2.** Locate the widget itself in the desired position at the available space of the sizer.
You could use the `position` parameter of `StaticText` for that purpose. But this would have the same problems indicated above for the use of `size`. So again you want to control the geometry of your views with sizers.
You position the widget in the sizer using one of:

```
sizer_6.Add(self.label_5, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0)
```

or

```
sizer_7.Add(self.label_6, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
```

For some reason, for this to work you need a vertical `BoxSizer` (and in the same way, if you would like to use wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL you will need an horizontal `BoxSizer`:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.panel_4 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.label_5 = wx.StaticText(self.panel_4, -1, "label_5")
        self.panel_5 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.label_6 = wx.StaticText(self.panel_5, -1, "label_6")
        self.panel_6 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.label_7 = wx.StaticText(self.panel_6, -1, "label_7")

        self.panel_4.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 255, 255))
        self.panel_5.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(127, 255, 0))
        self.panel_6.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(219, 112, 219))

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_8 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_7 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer_6.Add(self.label_5, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0)
        sizer_7.Add(self.label_6, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
        sizer_8.Add(self.label_7, 0, 0, 0)

        self.panel_4.SetSizer(sizer_6)
        self.panel_5.SetSizer(sizer_7)
        self.panel_6.SetSizer(sizer_8)

        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_5, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_6, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
```

This option implies a combination of panels and sizers that produces a code that is more difficult to simplify than that shown for the first option.

Comment: oh god !, I came to my own answer !!! Thanks me_in_the_past, to take your time answering these questions on SO so lenghty

Answer (score 1):

I think that text is not aligned because the size is not set. Try:

```
t1=wx.StaticText(smth, label="foo", pos=(0,0), size=(200,20), style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
t2=wx.StaticText(smth, label="bar", pos=(0,0), size=(200,20), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
```

And it will be aligned inside a 200*20 box. By default the size is "auto" i.e. (-1,-1) i.e. just enough for the text to be visible, and aligning in that box will not give *visible* effect.

[However, this does not always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587060/wxpython-text-alignment-does-not-work).

Comment: `However, this does not always work.` Because you are doing it wrong. If you set the size of the text this way you are setting a FIX size so when you change the size of your frame the center, right positions of the text is lost. If you want to keep your text aligned independly of the size of your frame/panel you must use sizers. See my answer. Despite downvoted it always work

Comment: `However, this does not always work`. Sorry that's true if you are using Ubuntu with wxPython 2.8.10.1. Contrarily, it works on windows. In ubuntu you can use the second, tested strategy on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem yesterday, I use MAC OS X, wxpython 4.0.6.
At last I find out this script works for me.

And I realise that if u don't SetSizer at last, the statictext will not align at center.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez7Sm.png)

Comment: Please don't include your code as an image. Instead, please [edit] your answer to include it as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).